# Why fscanf / scanf is changing the value of previously scanned variable on Ideone.com?

Tags: c, variables, scanf

I wrote a simple code on Ideone.com. The value of variable f is changing after execution of the command fscanf for taking the input string in next line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = stdin;
    int i=0, f,arr[3], count =0;
    char inp[3];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=0;
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &f);
    printf("%d\n", f);
    for(i;i<f;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", f);
        fscanf(fp , "%s\n", inp);
        printf("%d\n", f);
        if(inp[2]=='2')
            arr[1]++;
        else if(inp[0]=='1')
            arr[0]++;
        else
            arr[2]++;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",f, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
return 0;
}
```

The input I provided was

```
10
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
3/4
```

But the value of f is changing from 10 to 0 after the first scanf.

Comment: http://ideone.com/24tVSB

Comment: In addition to a larger buffer drop `\n`  --> `char inp[3+1]; fscanf(fp , "%3s", inp);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the terminating null-character, the allocated size for `inp` is too small. It seems `f` *happened* to be just after `inp` and your machine is using little endian, so the null-character is *happened* to be written to the first byte of `f` and `10` is smaller than `255`, so it made the value of `f` zero. Note that writing data to out-of-range of an array will invoke *undefined behavior*, so anything can happen.

To fix, do allocate sufficient buffer to `inp`.

Comment: yup, I changed the
    inp    
array size to 4 to accommodate null character and it worked. Thanks :)